# Checking raster values are within range of datatype

Tags: r, gis, raster, spatial, terra

I'm working with raster data in the {terra} package. I want to store my data in an optimum datatype for storage and speed. So for example,  I run a function, and it outputs integer data between 1 and 200. So I save the raster as INT1U which has range 0 to 255, rather than as FLT4S, which can deal with decimals and a much large range. My query though is that if I have data which does not match the type I am writing, it becomes NA. I'd prefer an error (as it tells me there is data I am not expecting in the output). Any thoughts on how to do that? My current effort:

Illustration of my problem:

```
library(terra)

test_rast <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(-10, 50, 100, 10000000000))

test_rast <- writeRaster(test_rast, 'test.tif', wopt = list(datatype = 'INT1U'), overwrite=TRUE)

values(test_rast)

     lyr.1
[1,]   NaN
[2,]    50
[3,]   100
[4,]   NaN
```

One solution I thought was to test. Something like this:

```
library(terra)

test_rast <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(-10, 50, 100, 10000000000))

int1u_min <- 0
int1u_max <- 254

if (minmax(test_rast)[[1]] >= int1u_min & minmax(test_rast)[[2]] < int1u_max) {
    test_rast <- writeRaster(test_rast, 'test.tif', wopt = list(datatype = 'INT1U'), overwrite=TRUE)
} else {
    stop()
}
```

As you can see it is not a very elegant solution. Plus I will have to manually set the acceptable min and max of each raster datatype range. Probably by copying this table into my script.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.5-15/topics/dataType

Is there a better way?

Comment: This is maybe a rather stupid idea, but if `terra` does not provide native warnings and you consider working with `stop()` anyway, maybe something like `vals = c(-10, 50, 100, 1000); dtype = "INT1U"; rng <- switch(dtype, "INT1U" = c(0, 255)); checkmate::assert_numeric(vals, lower = rng[1], upper = rng[2])` inside a little wrapper would also work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With terra >= 1.6-6 you now get a warning.

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(-10, 50, 100, 10000000000))
r <- writeRaster(r, 'test.tif', datatype = 'INT1U', overwrite=TRUE)
#Warning message:
#[writeRaster] detected values outside of the limits of datatype INT1U
```

Comment: More a question than an error, but do you think that there should be a warning when writeRaster rounds floats to integers also?

Comment: For example if we use INT4U with a value of 10.23423 the value stored in the raster is 10. I think it truncates.

Comment: I do not think a warning is necessary; as in that case you clearly get what you ask for.

Comment: Fair enough thanks